# Python .replace() function doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to modify a table I scraped of Yahoo Finance containing dividends over the last 5 years.

An example row of this table is: `"1.50 Dividend"`. As I want to do calculations with this table I needed only the number in the form of a float. So I used the `.replace("Dividend, "")` function to remove the text part so the `float()` function would be able to convert it.

When doing this I'm always met with following error:

```
TypeError: could not convert string to float: '1.50 Dividend'
```

It seems like the `.replace("Dividend", "")` simply doesn't do anything.

This is the code:

```
#Fetching Yahoo Finance dividend table (5y)
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/history?period1=1491782400&period2=1649548800&interval=capitalGain%7Cdiv%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    header = {   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }  
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)  
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text) 
    
    dividends = dfs[0]["Dividends"]
    
    dividends = dividends.head(5)
    counter = 0
    if len(dividends) > 2:
        while counter != len(dividends):
            dividend_string = dividends[counter]
            dividends[counter] = float(dividend_string.replace(" Dividend", ""))
            counter += 1
            sigma = dividends.std()
    else:
        sigma = 0
    sigma_ratio = sigma / dividends.mean()

    return sigma_ratio
```

I've tried using `.replace()` in a small test script and there it seems to work perfectly. I'm at the end of my rope.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Could you provide a `dividend_string` example? Right now it is kind of opaque to inspect what your input is.

Comment: Take a closer look at your string, and make sure it does not contain any invisible characters, or characters that look like other characters.

Comment: Your problem is not the replace function that works perfectly but the fact that your calculation of sigma is inside your while loop. Which means that you try to calculate sigma before you convert every strings to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem it's not in the `.replace()`, but in the `dividends.std()`.

Move `sigma = dividends.std()` outside the while loop, right now you're removing "Dividend" from just the first element then trying to call `dividends.std()` but the rest of the array still have Dividend inside.

```py
#Fetching Yahoo Finance dividend table (5y)
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/history?period1=1491782400&period2=1649548800&interval=capitalGain%7Cdiv%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    header = {   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }  
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)  
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text) 
    
    dividends = dfs[0]["Dividends"]
    
    dividends = dividends.head(5)
    counter = 0
    if len(dividends) > 2:
        while counter != len(dividends):
            dividend_string = dividends[counter]
            dividends[counter] = float(dividend_string.replace(" Dividend", ""))
            counter += 1
        sigma = dividends.std() # <-----
    else:
        sigma = 0
    sigma_ratio = sigma / dividends.mean()

    return sigma_ratio
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick. I knew it was going to be something simple, but I somehow missed it.